# How to use Terragrunt in Github Actions

Tags: terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-gcp, terragrunt

I am relatively new with creating custom github action workflows. I am trying to utilize Terragrunt with Terraform to automate my CICD workflow using Github Actions which provisions resources in a GCP account.
I have gotten a Terraform Github Actions to work but I am now trying to expand it to a modular approach using Terragrunt wrapped around Terraform. I have tested my terragrunt script locally and I have no issues. But I am having trouble setting up the Terragrunt Github Actions `workflow.yaml`

Where do I find the "`uses`" repo for Terragrunt to setup Terragrunt. I searched Hasicorp's github repo's and they only list Terraform. I have only found older workflows only for AWS for Terragrunt.

Here is my current `workflow.yaml`:

```
name: 'Terragrunt CI'

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
  pull_request:

jobs:
  Terragrunt:
    name: 'Terragrunt'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Use the Bash shell regardless whether the GitHub Actions runner is ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, or windows-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
    # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    # Install the latest version of Terragrunt CLI and configure the Terragrunt CLI configuration file with a Terragrunt Cloud user API token
    - name: Setup Terragrunt
      uses: #**TBD-hashicorp/setup-Terragrunt@v1**


    # Initialize a new or existing Terragrunt working directory by creating initial files, loading any remote state, downloading modules, etc.
    - name: Terragrunt Init
      run: terragrunt init --terragrunt-non-interactive
      env:
        GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}

    # Generates an execution plan for Terragrunt
    - name: Terragrunt Plan
      run: terragrunt run-all plan --terragrunt-non-interactive
      env:
        GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}

      # On push to main, build or change infrastructure according to Terragrunt configuration files
      # Note: It is recommended to set up a required "strict" status check in your repository for "Terragrunt Cloud". See the documentation on "strict" required status checks for more information: https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/types-of-required-status-checks
    - name: Terragrunt Apply
      if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && github.event_name == 'push'
      run: terragrunt apply-all --terragrunt-non-interactive
      env:
        GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Ah hey! :p How to get the workflow to setup Terragrunt? I could not find a repo in hashicorp's github for Terragrunt. There Terraform github action which worked for me previously to install Terraform only was, `uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1`

Comment: Terragrunt is a separate product of a different company, so not sure if you would be able to find it there.

Comment: Oh your correct, I thought it was also released by hashicorp. Do I just point the setup to here? https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt, e.g. `uses: gruntwork-io/terragrunt@v0.38.6`
Not exactly sure how github actions executes these based on github repo's yet...

Comment: Usually it provides all the commands you would need to perform any of the actions locally. You can define a base image (I think) like Ubuntu and use the action to run terragrunt commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Confirmed, this [workflow](https://github.com/Block-Farms/GCP-Github-Actions-Terragrunt/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow.yaml) confirmed works.

```
name: 'Terragrunt CI'

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
  pull_request:

jobs:
  Terragrunt:
    name: 'Terragrunt'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Use the Bash shell regardless whether the GitHub Actions runner is ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, or windows-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
    # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    # Install the latest version of Terragrunt CLI and configure the Terragrunt CLI configuration file with a Terragrunt Cloud user API token
    - name: Setup Terraform v1.2.6
      uses: hashicorp/setup-Terraform@v1
      with:
        terraform_version: 1.2.6
        terraform_wrapper: true
    - name: Setup Terraform version
      run: terraform --version
    - name: Setup Terraform wrapper path
      run: which terraform

    - name: Setup Terragrunt v0.38.4
      run: |
        sudo wget -q -O /bin/terragrunt "https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/releases/download/v0.38.4/terragrunt_linux_amd64"
        sudo chmod +x /bin/terragrunt
        terragrunt -v

    # Initialize a new or existing Terragrunt working directory by creating initial files, loading any remote state, downloading modules, etc.
    - name: Terragrunt Init
      run: terragrunt init --terragrunt-non-interactive
      env:
        GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}

    # Generates an execution plan for Terragrunt
    - name: Terragrunt Plan
      run: terragrunt run-all plan --terragrunt-non-interactive
      env:
        GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}

      # On push to main, build or change infrastructure according to Terragrunt configuration files
      # Note: It is recommended to set up a required "strict" status check in your repository for "Terragrunt Cloud". See the documentation on "strict" required status checks for more information: https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/types-of-required-status-checks
    - name: Terragrunt Apply
      if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && github.event_name == 'push'
      run: terragrunt run-all apply --terragrunt-non-interactive
      env:
        GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}
```

Answer (score 1):

## 2023 update

It should be possible to use this action https://github.com/autero1/action-terragrunt now.

This section must be added to the corresponding action therefore:

```
  - name: Setup Terragrunt
    uses: autero1/action-terragrunt@v1.1.0
    with:
      terragrunt_version: 0.21.13
      token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

and respective a full config like this:

```
name: 'Terragrunt CI'

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
  pull_request:

jobs:
  Terragrunt:
    name: 'Terragrunt'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    # Install the latest version of Terragrunt CLI and configure the Terragrunt CLI configuration file with a Terragrunt Cloud user API token
    - name: Setup Terraform v1.2.6
      uses: hashicorp/setup-Terraform@v1
      with:
        terraform_version: 1.2.6
        terraform_wrapper: true
    - name: Setup Terraform version
      run: terraform --version
    - name: Setup Terraform wrapper path
      run: which terraform

    - name: Setup Terragrunt version 0.21.13
      uses: autero1/action-terragrunt@v1.1.0
      with:
        terragrunt_version: 0.21.13
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    # Initialize a new or existing Terragrunt working directory by creating initial files, loading any remote state, downloading modules, etc.
    - name: Terragrunt Init
      run: terragrunt init --terragrunt-non-interactive
```

Comment: Agyss, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)